# addFieldToFilter in magento2 returning same data everytime

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.2, magento2.3, magento-2.0

addfieldtofilter in magento2 behaving weirdly

I have code

```
   foreach($userIDs as $singleUserID) {               
            $userid=$singleUserID['user_id'];
            var_dump($userid);//everytime for loop runs values changes 1,2,3
            $userDetails = $this->userCollection ->addFieldToFilter('user_id',$userid); 
            var_dump($userDetails->getData());/* output: array('id'=>1,'user_id'=>1,'user_name'=>'a'); 
                                array('id'=>1,'user_id'=>1,'user_name'=>'a'); 
                                array('id'=>1,'user_id'=>1,'user_name'=>'a');   */      
            }
```

same code If I write with passing value then it gives correct data

```
    foreach($userIDs as $singleUserID) {               
            $userid=$singleUserID['user_id'];
            var_dump($userid);//everytime for loop runs values changes 1,2,3

           // If I am passing direct value 1 or 2 or 3. getting correct data

          $userDetails = $this->userCollection->addFieldToFilter('user_id',3); 
            var_dump($userDetails->getData());/*output: array('id'=>1,'user_id'=>1,'user_name'=>'a');  for 1 
                   array('id'=>2,'user_id'=>2,'user_name'=>'b');   for 2
                   array('id'=>3,'user_id'=>3,'user_name'=>'c');   for 3 */      
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Now I able to get correct Data, I changed **userCollection** class to **userCollectionfactory** class

> use Vendor\MyModule\Model\ResourceModel\Users\CollectionFactory as UserCollectionFactory;

Every time foreach runs User id changes and addFieldToFilter gives correct user details w.r.t userID

```
 foreach($userIDs as $singleUserID) {               
        $userid=$singleUserID['user_id'];
        var_dump($userid);//everytime values changes 1,2,3
        $userDetails = $this->userCollectionFactory->create() ->addFieldToFilter('user_id',$userid); 
        var_dump($userDetails->getData());// output: 
                            array('id'=>1,'user_id'=>1,'user_name'=>'a'); 
                            array('id'=>2,'user_id'=>2,'user_name'=>'b'); 
                            array('id'=>3,'user_id'=>3,'user_name'=>'c');         
        }
```

Comment: Please do accept as an answer so others would use it